# export tortoise hg version control data to excel to visualize development process

Tags: excel, export, tortoisehg, visualize

I am working on a game development project with Unity3D using TortoiseHg to track our files. We are nearing the end of development and we would like to prepare a deliverable that displays our development data in a nice info-graphic, like this image below

[image]

I am aware of how to create the charts, I am just having trouble understanding how to export the data in an easy to read format from TortoiseHg. I would like to export all this data if possible:

[image]

If someone could assist me in educating me on a method of exporting the above data into a spreadsheet I would appreciate it.

Thanks,

-Naeem

Answer (score 0):

Well, in any case you have to use CLI version on Mercurial (`hg` in command prompt, with always exist behind the scene of TortoiseHG)

If you see at log pane, you have to use `hg log` and include in output all needed for you data and format it in way, usable for importing into spreadsheet (CSV isn't bad choice)

In order to write  full log command, you have to know, which details about commit you have to have in data-file as result (forhet about format, think about content)

AFAICS from graph, for each commit you have to know

- Month of commit
- Day of month
- Time (local or GMT?)

Is it the full list of requirements?